# How do I properly use mock functionality for testing purposes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, mixins

I am new to using mixins, and I am more familiar with Java-based dependency injection.

Let's say I use a mixin module to provide database connectivity for a class, as described at http://fabiokung.com/2010/05/06/ruby-and-dependency-injection-in-a-dynamic-world/ :

```
module ConnectionProvider
  def connection
    # open a database connection and return it
  end
end

# reopening the class to mix the module in
class Repository
  include ConnectionProvider
end
```

This allows me to do this:

```
class Repository
  def find(id)
    connection.execute("SELECT ...")
  end
end
```

Now I don't have to pass a ConnectionProvider object in via the Repository initializer.

Let's say I want to use a mock version of ConnectionProvider for testing purposes, and so I want to include MockConnectionProvider in Repository instead of ConnectionProvider. Both ConnectionProvider and MockConnectionProvider provide the method *connection*. Here is how I think this is supposed to be done.

---

**For my normal Rails app**

In environment.rb:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib/repository"
```

**For my test scripts**

In my test files:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib/repository_mocked"
```

---

Is this correct? If not, can someone provide a link to an article demonstrating the proper way?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a mocking library to do this kind of things. I usually use [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) which has a good interface, with that you can write code like

```
mocked_value = # anything you want
Repository.any_instance.stubs(:find).returns(mocked_value)
```

So every call to `Repository#find` will return the `mocked_value`

Other mocking libraries are:

- [rspec](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks)
- [flexmock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just mock 'connection' method.

As module has been included to the class its methods are treated as methods of this class.

If you'd like to mock a bunch of related methods you can rewrite your class which uses an instance of ConnectionProvider class (yes, change it to class from module) for example. So in this way you can mock this ConnectionProvider instance object.

UPD: you should not mess with files for mocking. Use special mocking tools as Fabio told you. ;)